# "dpkg: error processing package" and "dependency problems; leaving unconfigured" errors when I try to update

Tags: apt, package-management

```
lurkingandjerking@rad-pad:~$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
[sudo] password for lurkingandjerking: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ubuntu-restricted-extras is already the newest version (66).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  lsdvd
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
41 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Setting up libpam-systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.23) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package libpam-systemd:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libpam-systemd:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up cups (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.6) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package cups (--configure):
 installed cups package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dbus-user-session:
 dbus-user-session depends on libpam-systemd; however:
  Package libpam-systemd:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package dbus-user-session (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up cups-bsd (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.6) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package cups-bsd (--configure):
 installed cups-bsd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up libssl1.1:amd64 (1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.3) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package libssl1.1:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libssl1.1:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up libssl1.1:i386 (1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.3) ...No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package libssl1.1:i386 (--configure):
 installed libssl1.1:i386 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
        dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-cryptography:
 python-cryptography depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1); however:
  Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-cryptography (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libdns-export1100:
 libdns-export1100 depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0); however:
  Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libdns-export1100 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openssl:
 openssl depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1); however:
  Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package openssl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libdvd-pkg (1.4.2-1-1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package libdvd-pkg (--configure):
 installed libdvd-pkg package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libdns1100:amd64:
 libdns1100:amd64 depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0); however:
  Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libdns1100:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64:
 libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64 depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0); however:
  Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bind9-host:
 bind9-host depends on libdns1100 (= 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.8); however:
  Package libdns1100:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package bind9-host (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-cryptography:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                      No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 python3-cryptography depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1); however:
  Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-cryptography (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libisc169:amd64:
 libisc169:amd64 depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0); however:
  Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libisc169:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libisccc160:amd64:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                   No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 libisccc160:amd64 depends on libisc169 (= 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.8); however:
  Package libisc169:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libisccc160:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt5network5:amd64:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 libqt5network5:amd64 depends on libssl1.1; however:
  Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libqt5network5:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnet-ssleay-perl:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 libnet-ssleay-perl depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1); however:
  Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libnet-ssleay-perl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libisc-export169:amd64:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 libisc-export169:amd64 depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0); however:
  Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libisc-export169:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libirs160:amd64:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 libirs160:amd64 depends on libisc169 (= 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.8); however:
  Package libisc169:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libirs160:amd64 depends on libdns1100 (>= 1:9.11.3+dfsg); however:
  Package libdns1100:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libirs160:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcurl4:amd64:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 libcurl4:amd64 depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0); however:
  Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libcurl4:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libbind9-160:amd64:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 libbind9-160:amd64 depends on libdns1100 (= 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.8); however:
  Package libdns1100:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libbind9-160:amd64 depends on libisc169 (= 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.8); however:
  Package libisc169:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libbind9-160:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python2.7:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 python2.7 depends on libpython2.7-stdlib (= 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04); however:
  Package libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python2.7 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dnsutils:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 dnsutils depends on bind9-host | host; however:
  Package bind9-host is not configured yet.
  Package host is not installed.
  Package bind9-host which provides host is not configured yet.
 dnsutils depends on libbind9-160 (= 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.8); however:
  Package libbind9-160:amd64 is not configured yet.
 dnsutils depends on libdns1100 (= 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.8); however:
  Package libdns1100:amd64 is not configured yet.
 dnsutils depends on libisc169 (= 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.8); however:
  Package libisc169:amd64 is not configured yet.
 dnsutils depends on libirs160 (>= 1:9.10.6+dfsg); however:
  Package libirs160:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package dnsutils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libio-socket-ssl-perl:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 libio-socket-ssl-perl depends on libnet-ssleay-perl (>= 1.84-1ubuntu0.1); however:
  Package libnet-ssleay-perl is not configured yet.
 libio-socket-ssl-perl depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1); however:
  Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libio-socket-ssl-perl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpython3.6-minimal:amd64:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 libpython3.6-minimal:amd64 depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1); however:
  Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpython3.6-minimal:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libisccfg160:amd64:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 libisccfg160:amd64 depends on libdns1100 (= 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.8); however:
  Package libdns1100:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libisccfg160:amd64 depends on libisc169 (= 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.8); however:
  Package libisc169:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libisccfg160:amd64 depends on libisccc160 (= 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.8); however:
  Package libisccc160:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libisccfg160:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openvpn:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 openvpn depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0); however:
  Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package openvpn (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt5gui5:amd64:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 libqt5gui5:amd64 depends on libqt5network5 (>= 5.0.2); however:
  Package libqt5network5:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libqt5gui5:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpython2.7:amd64:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 libpython2.7:amd64 depends on libpython2.7-stdlib (= 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04); however:
  Package libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpython2.7:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpython2.7-dev:amd64:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 libpython2.7-dev:amd64 depends on libpython2.7-stdlib (= 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04); however:
  Package libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libpython2.7-dev:amd64 depends on libpython2.7 (= 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04); however:
  Package libpython2.7:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpython2.7-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qt5-gtk-platformtheme:amd64:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 qt5-gtk-platformtheme:amd64 depends on libqt5gui5 (= 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.1); however:
  Package libqt5gui5:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qt5-gtk-platformtheme:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python2.7-dev:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 python2.7-dev depends on python2.7 (= 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04); however:
  Package python2.7 is not configured yet.
 python2.7-dev depends on libpython2.7-dev (= 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04); however:
  Package libpython2.7-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.
 python2.7-dev depends on libpython2.7 (= 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04); however:
  Package libpython2.7:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python2.7-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64 depends on libpython3.6-minimal (= 3.6.8-1~18.04.1); however:
  Package libpython3.6-minimal:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3.6:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 python3.6 depends on libpython3.6-stdlib (= 3.6.8-1~18.04.1); however:
  Package libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3.6 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of samba-libs:amd64:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 samba-libs:amd64 depends on libpython2.7 (>= 2.7); however:
  Package libpython2.7:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package samba-libs:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt5widgets5:amd64:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 libqt5widgets5:amd64 depends on libqt5gui5 (>= 5.9.0~beta); however:
  Package libqt5gui5:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libqt5widgets5:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of curl:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 curl depends on libcurl4 (= 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.7); however:
  Package libcurl4:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package curl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3.6-minimal:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 python3.6-minimal depends on libpython3.6-minimal (= 3.6.8-1~18.04.1); however:
  Package libpython3.6-minimal:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3.6-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libsmbclient:amd64:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 libsmbclient:amd64 depends on samba-libs (= 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.11); however:
  Package samba-libs:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libsmbclient:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mplayer:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 mplayer depends on libsmbclient (>= 2:4.0.3+dfsg1); however:
  Package libsmbclient:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mplayer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpam-systemd:amd64
 cups
 dbus-user-session
 cups-bsd
 libssl1.1:amd64
 libssl1.1:i386
 python-cryptography
 libdns-export1100
 openssl
 libdvd-pkg
 libdns1100:amd64
 libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64
 bind9-host
 python3-cryptography
 libisc169:amd64
 libisccc160:amd64
 libqt5network5:amd64
 libnet-ssleay-perl
 libisc-export169:amd64
 libirs160:amd64
 libcurl4:amd64
 libbind9-160:amd64
 python2.7
 dnsutils
 libio-socket-ssl-perl
 libpython3.6-minimal:amd64
 libisccfg160:amd64
 openvpn
 libqt5gui5:amd64
 libpython2.7:amd64
 libpython2.7-dev:amd64
 qt5-gtk-platformtheme:amd64
 python2.7-dev
 libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64
 python3.6
 samba-libs:amd64
 libqt5widgets5:amd64
 curl
 python3.6-minimal
 libsmbclient:amd64
 mplayer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
lurkingandjerking@rad-pad:~$ sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
sudo: /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh: command not found
lurkingandjerking@rad-pad:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for lurkingandjerking: 
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]   
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease    
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]    
Ign:5 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04  InRelease
Hit:6 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04  Release
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu bionic InRelease     
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/me-davidsansome/clementine/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:9 http://deb.playonlinux.com trusty InRelease                              
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu bionic InRelease        
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tiheum/equinox/ubuntu bionic InRelease       
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease         
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/apps/ubuntu bionic InRelease  
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu bionic InRelease 
Err:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu bionic Release     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/me-davidsansome/clementine/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release            
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [658 kB]
Err:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tiheum/equinox/ubuntu bionic Release           
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release            
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Get:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages [544 kB]
Get:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [278 kB]
Err:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu bionic Release    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Get:26 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [66.7 kB]
Get:27 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [127 kB]
Get:28 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [958 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages [943 kB]
Get:30 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [245 kB]
Get:31 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [198 kB]
Get:32 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [417 kB]
Get:33 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]
Get:35 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [17.9 kB]
Get:36 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [25.6 kB]
Get:37 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [36.2 kB]
Get:38 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [16.4 kB]
Get:39 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [104 kB]
Get:40 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,460 B]
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/me-davidsansome/clementine/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/tiheum/equinox/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Now this pops up

```
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Please post the complete output - the summary at the end does not contain enough information to offer you useful advice.

Comment: N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details. 

This now pops up wtf did I do wrong here, all I wanted was to install VLC codecs and it is giving me mud.

Comment: [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/)

Comment: SOLVED THANKS GUYS!!!!!!!!